# Vagrant Box LAMP Images

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, vmware, lamp, vagrant

Are there freely available Vagrant-box images for CentOS 6.xx 64bit that include the following LAMP stack? or should i just use a base CentOS image and build my own environment?

- PHP 5.4+
- Mcyrpt Extension
- Mysql 5.xx +
- Apache 2.xx

Im usually developing on the Laravel framework (PHP).

Comment: http://www.vagrantbox.es/ has some ready boxes with Lamp but none with CentOS AFAIK. You can add one if you make one - so might be useful for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant base boxes are minimal boxes, not likely to include LAMP/LEMP stack.

Vagrant supports various provisioning tools like chef, puppet, ansible.

If you know basics about chef cookbooks, just put the cookbooks together and edit the Vagrantfile before you `vagrant up`.

LAMP requires the following [cookbooks](http://community.opscode.com/)

- apache2
- php
- mysql
- openssl
- build-essential
- xml

Use a opscode [bento](https://github.com/opscode/bento) boxes and run the cookbooks.

Refer to [chef_solo](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html), add the recipes required to the runlist in the Vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "lamp"
  end
end
```

NOTE: in this example lamp includes the following recipes:

- apache2
- mysql::server
- mysql::ruby
- php
- php::module_mysql

Run `vagrant up` and it'll do the provisioning for you.